# Como funciona o "infer" do TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, característica-linguagem

Sei que foi introduzido na versão 2.8 da linguagem (veja [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)), mas apesar de ter lido essas notas de release, ainda não consegui entender o funcionamento de `infer`.

- Como funciona?
- Qual o seu real objetivo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O `infer` é usado em conjunto a [condições de tipos](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) no TypeScript porque ele irá tentar *inferir* um tipo e, caso não seja possível, algo deve acontecer. Por isso deve sempre estar em um *conditional type*.

Basicamente, `infer` irá "criar" um novo tipo, cujo nome virá à sua frente:

```
infer NewType ? [[conseguiu-inferir]] : [[não-conseguiu-inferir]]
```

Em que `NewType` será o tipo que for inferido. Nesse sentido, seremos capazes de utilizá-lo na "expressão  típica" que se posiciona em `[[conseguiu-inferir]]`.

Um exemplo:

```
type GetArrayMemberType<T> = T extends Array<infer Member> ? Member : T;

type A = GetArrayMemberType<string[]>; // A inferido para `string`
type B = GetArrayMemberType<string[][]>; // B inferido para `string[]`
type C = GetArrayMemberType<number>; // C inferido para `number`
```

<sup>[Link para o playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwEEBOSCGICyEC2AjCSAKuBADyEB8UAvFIVBAB7AQB2AJgM5TJoikBLVgDMCULHgJUA-OJz4kUAFx0A3AFgAUFtCQeNWPF7oJC4pFKdgSIQHMA2gF0KqqAHo3%20oaJvsA9lBgqGhQAAZWNqy2oTokUABCBnCIKCbyBOZkEXZOTi7unoneBAL%20gcGoYdlRTjGautAAwklGqZjpRCSkrACukkj5HlDNxb4BQSGhvf2hQA)</sup>

Quando tipos condicionais são usados em conjunto com o `infer` (que deve ocupar o primeiro operando da "condicional ternária"), o tipo do segundo operando (que geralmente é composto a partir do tipo inferido) é retornado. Caso a inferência do tipo não seja possível, o terceiro operando será retornado.

Pense nessa necessidade do `infer` precisar estar associado a um *conditional type* relacionando o sistema de tipos do TypeScript a uma *mini* linguagem de programação puramente *funcional*. Isso porque todo tipo do TypeScript *sempre* deve ser algo (assim como uma expressão em linguagens de programação funcionais). E o que aconteceria se o tipo não pudesse ser inferido e não fornecêssemos uma "cláusula *else*"? O tipo resultante deveria ser o quê?

Em suma, assim como um [`if` do Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/If-then-else) sempre precisa de um `else`, um tipo condicional do TypeScript também *sempre* precisa de um `else` (que se localiza no terceiro termo da construção ternária). Isso, associado ao `infer`, garante que sempre teremos um tipo válido, mesmo quando a inferência não ser possível.

Veja esta estrutura:

```
//|             Primeiro operando. O `infer` deve ficar nele.
//|                                │
//|                                │           ╔ Nome que será atribuído ao tipo inferido pelo `infer`.
//|                               ┌┴───────────║────┐
//|                               │           ╔╩═══╗│
1 | type UnpackArr<T> = T extends Array<infer Member>
//|    ┌ O segundo operando da condição será retornado caso a inferência tenha sido possível.
//|    │ Geralmente, esse tipo é composto a partir daquele que foi inferido (no caso, `Member`).
//|   ┌┴─────────────┐
2 | ? { type: Member }
//|   ┌ O terceiro operando da condição será retronado caso a inferência não tenha sido possível.
//|   │ Neste caso, só estamos retornando o tipo passado (`T`).
3 | : T;
```

Observe que um nome *sempre* deve ser colocado após o `infer`. É o nome que será dado ao tipo que será inferido. O nome poderá ser usado no segundo operando da condição de tipos.

> Qual o seu real objetivo?

O objetivo é conseguir inferir tipos. Na maioria das vezes, é usado para "desempacotar" um tipo, obtendo o valor de um tipo "interno".

Por exemplo, até a versão do TypeScript atual para quando escrevo esta resposta, a palavra-chave `awaited` ainda não existe no TypeScript. Portanto, a única forma de obter o tipo `T` de uma `Promise<T>` é a partir do `infer`. Veja:

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends Promise<infer Member> ? Member : T;

type A = Awaited<Promise<string>>; // A inferido `string`.
type B = Awaited<Promise<{ name: string, age: number }>>; // B inferido `{ name: string, age: number }`.
```

[Link para o playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg7gQwJbAgEwDwBUB8UC8UWUEAHqgHZoDOUACgE4D2AtktRBkhQGYQNQAshBYAjfngD8QkeIEAuIgG4AsACh1oSLAKxEKdBkat2nasAbcA5jhxKoAegc7ufS2iZQABucsUrXgB0muDQAEK68MiomMZsHBgA3lAUCCwQir7WADRQCFYZKQCuYvxQAL629k5QEa78SB7eyanpmRY5eQWKFCVyFUFAA)

Futuramente, `awaited Promise<T>` (uma construção que ainda não existe no TypeScript) retornará o tipo `T`, mas por ora a única forma de conseguir isso é usando condicionais de tipos em conjunto com `infer`.

Geralmente isso é mais útil para autores de bibliotecas ou alguma coisa que exija uma tipagem um pouco mais complexa.